# What is the meaning of numbers in UVM_INFO?

Tags: system-verilog, logfile, uvm, questasim

The following message is from a transcript file created by running QuestaSim to simulate dut. What does the number 39 mean?

```
UVM_INFO /home/Icer/nocc/noc-router/vips/hermes_pkg/src/hermes_agent.sv(39)
        @ 0: uvm_test_top.env.agent_master_0 [agent] PORT number: 0
```

In order to better understand the mechanism of the UVM sequence, I try to figure it out by understanding the log file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The number in the parentheses immediately after the file name, `39`, indicates the line number in the `hermes_agent.sv` source code file where the log message originates.  On line 39 of that file, you likely have a  `` `uvm_info() `` call.

In the UVM library source code,  `` `uvm_info() `` has this line:

```
   uvm_report_info (ID, MSG, VERBOSITY, `uvm_file, `uvm_line); \
```

where

```
`define uvm_line `__LINE__
```

Refer to IEEE Std 1800-2017, section 22.13 `` `__FILE__ and `__LINE__ `` :

```
`__LINE__ expands to the current input line number, 
in the form of a simple decimal number.
```

See also: [uvm_info](https://verificationacademy.com/verification-methodology-reference/uvm/docs_1.1c/html/files/macros/uvm_message_defines-svh.html#%60uvm_info)